# Can't dynamically import using exec from function despite success using interpreter

Tags: python, python-import

I'm having some trouble importing some stuff using a function, despite being able to do so in the interpreter.

Imagine there is a file, input.py, in a folder A which in turn is in the same directory as my script. In this file, we define variable 'B'.

```
B = 5
```

When I go into the interpreter, the following commands give me the correct value of B

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('A')
>>> exec('from inputs import *')
>>> print(B)
```

Yet if I move that code to a seperate file, say 'test.py':

```
import sys

def import_stuff(import_dir):
    sys.path.append(import_dir)
    exec('from inputs import *')
    print(B)
```

Then call it from the interpreter like so:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.import_stuff('A')
```

I get a NameError and B is not found. What's going on?

Comment: you mistyped `inputs` instead of `input`

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. However, that is a typo made when transferring the code to stack overflow and does not exist in my my original code. Question fixed.

Comment: Is your file also named `inputs.py` instead of `input.py`?

Comment: Yes. (Char limit)

Comment: Works for me. Check in file is actually imported. Replace print(B) with print(locals())

Comment: Interesting. Print(locals()) works and B is in the map returned. I can access it with locals()['B'], which is an acceptable workaround for my purposes. Still, I'm confused about the inconsistency.

Comment: I'm out of ideas as it works for me. What python version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local variables in functions are treated differently than global variables and object attributes (which both use dictionaries to map names to values).

When a function is defined, the Python compiler examines its code and makes a note of which local variable names are used, and designates a "slot" for each one. When the function is called, the slots refer to part of the memory in the frame object. Local variable assignments and lookups access the slots by number, not by name. This makes local variable lookups notably faster than global variable and attribute lookups (since indexing a slot is much faster than doing a dict lookup).

When you try to use `exec` to create local variables, it bypasses the slots. The compiler doesn't know what variables will be created in the `exec`'d code, so there are no slots allocated for them. This is also the reason Python 3 doesn't allow you to use `from module import *` inside a function: the names to be imported are not known at the function's compile time (only when it is run and the imported module is loaded) so the compiler can't set up slots for the names.

Even if you separately initialized local variables for the names you expect to be assigned to in the `exec`'d code, it still wouldn't work. The `exec`'d code doesn't know it's being run from within a function, and always wants to write variables to a dictionary (never to function slots). Function's do have a local namespace dictionary that does catch the assignments (they don't become global variables), but using it via the `locals()` function is very flaky. The values of all of the local variables stored in slots are copied into the dictionary each time you call `locals()`, but no copying in the other direction ever happens (modifying the dictionary returned from `locals()` doesn't effect the values of variables stored in slots and accessed the normal way).

That brings me to what I think is the best way to work around this issue. Rather than having `exec` modify the current namespace (which occurs in a flaky way if you're in a function), you should explicitly pass in a dictionary for it to use as its namespace.

```
def import_stuff(import_dir):
    sys.path.append(import_dir)
    namespace = {}                           # create a namespace dict
    exec('from inputs import *', namespace)  # pass it to exec
    print(namespace["B"])                    # read the results from the namespace
```